# Docker with Compose and Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine, docker-swarm

I'm trying to setup my server infrastructure using compose and swarm. Basically I want to have a setup (pretty much) mirroring this example from the Docker website on Digital Ocean droplets.

https://docs.docker.com/swarm/swarm_at_scale/deploy-app/

This is the output from running docker-compose up:

```
docker-compose up -d
Creating network "scale_voteapp" with the default driver
Creating volume "scale_db-data" with default driver
Pulling db (postgres:9.4)...
worker01: Pulling postgres:9.4... : downloaded
dbstore: Pulling postgres:9.4... : downloaded
frontend01: Pulling postgres:9.4... : downloaded
frontend02: Pulling postgres:9.4... : downloaded
Creating db
Pulling redis (redis:latest)...
dbstore: Pulling redis:latest... : downloaded
frontend01: Pulling redis:latest... : downloaded
frontend02: Pulling redis:latest... : downloaded
worker01: Pulling redis:latest... : downloaded
Creating redis
```

From this, it appears that every service is getting installed on every machine... so worker01 will have postgres, redis etc. installed on it instead of just having the worker image installed as implied in the diagram.

So my question is pretty much just, is this what's happening and is this how it's supposed to work? Is every service getting mapped onto every machine (and if so is every service running on every machine?) or is each service mapped to a single physical machine within the cluster?

Cheers,
Aaron

Comment: From the above we only see that container images get downloaded to multiple machines. Why wouldn't you check where they are running and in which numbers? I guess `docker ps` will show that...

Answer (score 2):

Every image is being downloaded to every node. That way if a container needs to be restarted on a different node, the image is available. However, the services won't be started on every node, so only the disk space is used, no other resources.